# Ambient data as AsyncLocal

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I have created an `AmbientDataProvider` that is intended to be to access query params that are set in a lot of my requests. In a few cases, I would like to set it manually, e.g.

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult SomeAction()
{
    _ambientDataProvider.SetRequestId("123");

    return Ok();
}
```

Is there any point of keeping it as `AsyncLocal` below? Since the class has a scoped lifestyle, I guess I might as well use a private string?

```
public class AmbientDataProvider : IAmbientDataProvider
{
    private readonly AsyncLocal<string> _requestId = new AsyncLocal<string>();
    public string RequestId => _requestId.Value ?? HttpContext.Current?.Request.QueryString["requestId"];

    public void SetRequestId(string requestId)
    {
        _requestId.Value = requestId;
    }
}
```

My container configuration

```
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();
container.Register<IAmbientDataProvider, AmbientDataProvider>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it comes to pushing runtime data through an object graph, there are two [DI Composition Models](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2019/di-composition-models-primer/) to choose from: [Ambient Composition Model](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2019/ambient-composition-model/) and [Closure Composition Model](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2019/closure-composition-model/).

You seem to mixing the two models. With the Closure Composition Model you store runtime data (your request id) in a (private) field inside a component, whereas with the Ambient Composition Model, you store that runtime data as ambient state (for instance using `AsyncLocal<T>`).

When using the Ambient Composition Model, you can make your `AmbientDataProvider` singleton, because the `AsyncLocal<T>` already ensures isolation of runtime data per request. When your data provider is a Scoped component, however, you can also store the data in a private field.